# How to fill a section between two curves inside a defined range?

Tags: gnuplot

I am writing a report and need to make some nice plots to explain my problem. To do so, I would like to plot two curves f(x) and g(x) and fill the space between xmin and xmax. Is there a way to do it? By the way I am using gnuplot 5.2
I have tried this but without success:

```
f(x) = 1+x
g(x) = 1-x
plot '+' using (x >= 0.75 && x < 1 ? 1 : 1/0 ):(f($1)):(g($1)) with filledcurves closed
```

Answer (score 2):

The command you show is close to working.  Modify it to be

```
  plot '+' using (x >= 0.75 && x < 1 ? $1 : 1/0 ):(f($1)):(g($1)) with filledcurves
```

note that

- the filter is `(condition ? $1 : 1/0)`  not `(condition ? 1 : 1/0)`
- do not use the keyword `closed`
- you must have a reasonable number of samples over the range being selected. One way to get this would be `set samples 1000` but see alternative below

A slightly better method might to use a sampling range rather than a filter on x.

```
  f(x) = 1+x
  g(x) = 1-x
  set xrange [0:2]; set yrange [0:3]
  plot sample [x=0.75:1.0] '+' using ($1):(f($1)):(g($1)) with filledcurves
```

[image]